# Why do I get an incomplete type in my C code?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, incomplete-type

I have two header files, namely `point.h` and `polygon.h`

```
//point.h
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

typedef struct Point point;

point *alloc_point(void);
int free_point(point *);
void init_point(point *, float, float);
void print_point(point *);

#endif
```

and

```
//polygon.h
#ifndef POLYGON_H
#define POLYGON_H

typedef struct Polygon polygon;

polygon *alloc_polygon(void);
int free_polygon(polygon *);
void init_polygon(polygon *, unsigned, point *);
void print_polygon(polygon *);

#endif
```

with the corresponding `point.c` and `polygon.c` files

```
//point.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

point *alloc_point(void)
{
    point *pt = (point *)malloc(sizeof(point));

    if (pt)
    {
        return pt;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate point. Aborting\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int free_point(point *pt)
{
    if (pt)
    {
        free(pt);
        pt = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not free point. Aborting\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

void init_point(point *pt, float x, float y)
{
    pt->x = x;
    pt->y = y;
}

void print_point(point *pt)
{
    printf("Point at (%f, %f)\n", pt->x, pt->y);
}
```

and

```
//polygon.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"

struct Polygon
{
    unsigned nside;
    point *centre;
};

polygon *alloc_polygon(void)
{
    polygon *poly = (polygon *)malloc(sizeof(polygon));

    if (poly)
    {
        return poly;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate polygon. Aborting\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int free_polygon(polygon *poly)
{
    if (poly)
    {
        free(poly);
        poly = NULL;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot free polygon. Aborting\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void init_polygon(polygon *poly, unsigned nside, point *centre)
{
    poly->nside = nside;
    poly->centre = centre;
}

void print_polygon(polygon *poly)
{
    printf("%u-sided polygon with centre at (%f, %f)",
           poly->nside, poly->centre->x, poly->centre->y);
}
```

When I try to run `main.c`, which contains

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"
#include "polygon.h"

int main() {
    point *centre = alloc_point();
    init_point(centre, 10.0, 10.0);
    print_point(centre);

    unsigned nside = 4;
    polygon *poly = alloc_polygon();
    init_polygon(poly, nside, centre);
    print_polygon(poly);

    free_point(centre);
    free_polygon(poly);
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error message (coming from the `print_polygon` method inside `polygon.c`)

> error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'point' {aka 'struct Point'}

I do not get that error as the definition of the `Polygon` structure has a pointer to `point`. Why can I not get the code running?

P.S.: I use gcc 8.1.0 and compile using
`gcc -Os -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -std=c99 .\main.c .\point.c .\polygon.c -o .\main.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `poly -> centre -> x`, `poly -> centre` is a pointer to a `point`, and `-> x` dereferences that `point`, but `polygon.c` does not have a complete definition of `point`. It only knows `point` is `struct Point` but not what the contents of `struct Point` are.

Some options to fix this are:

1. Define a routine in `point.c` that will print the point’s coordinates, export that routine from `point.c` (via `point.h`), and call it from `print_polygon`.
2. Define a routine or routines in `point.c` that will provide the coordinates, export that routine or routines, and call it or them from `print_polygon` to get the values to print.
3. Make the definition of `struct Point` visible in `polygon`.

The first is best for preserving modularity.

(In 2, the coordinates could be provided by returning them from one routine in a structure whose definition is shared between `point.c` and `polygon.c`, by returning the two `float` coordinates in separate routines, one for each, or by returning the two `float` coordinates in `float` objects passed by reference.)

Comment: Why does `polygon.c` not have a definition of `point`, since `polygon.c` does include `point.h`?

Comment: @aheuchamps: `point.h` does not have a definition of the structure. It has `typedef struct Point point;`, whichndoes define `point` to be an alias of `struct Point`, but the definition of `struct Point` is incomplete there. It is only known to be a structure; its contents are unknown.

Answer (score 3):

In this structure declaration

```
struct Polygon
{
    unsigned nside;
    point *centre;
};
```

there is used a pointer of the type `point *` where the type `point` is incomplete because within the module `polygon.c` there is no definition of the structure `Point` that has the typedef name `point`.

So compiling the function

```
void print_polygon(polygon *poly)
{
    printf("%u-sided polygon with centre at (%f, %f)", poly -> nside, poly -> centre -> x, poly -> centre -> y);
}
```

the compiler does not know whether `point` (the structure `Point`) indeed has data members `x` and `y`.

As a result the error message is issued by the compiler.

You need also to include the definition of the structure `Point` in this module.

Comment: I do not understand: since `polygon.c` includes `point.h` (where the definition `typedef struct Point point` is present), why is the type incomplete?

Comment: @aheuchamps There is only declaration of two type specifiers: incomplete struct Point and typedef name point. But it is unknown what data members the structure struct Point has. How should the compiler know that the structure contains exactly data members x and y and for example not v and w? The compiler needs the definition of the structure to be able to compile the function correctly.

Comment: I think I got it: if I link what you say with the answer of @Eric Postpischil here beneath: I could have named the components of my `Point` structure with any name, the compiler would not know anythong about it. So, inside `point.h` and `point.c` I should write methods to return the field values and use those methods inside `polygon.c`, am I right?

Comment: @aheuchamps Or you can in point.c  write a function that outputs data members x and y of an object of the structure type and call this function inside print_polygon.

Comment: Very good, will do. Thank you for your help

Comment: @aheuchamps No at all. You are welcome.